# Uso do SignalIR

Tags: asp.net, signalr

Estou desenvolvendo um chat em SignalIR, e eu apenas consigo enviar as mensagens para todos os Usuários logados, usando dessa forma:

```
public void Send(string name, string message)
{            
    Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
}
```

Gostaria de enviar para um usuário específico, como posso fazer isso ?

Comment: Está usando Asp ?

Comment: Sim, se quiser mando o código completo

Comment: Eu encontrei aqui no SOen um exemplo que funcionou comigo. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522103/signalr-sending-a-message-to-a-specific-user-using-iuseridprovider-new-2-0

Comment: Não deu certo aqui, É possivel eu usar o `$.connection.hub.id`para isso?

Comment: Eu utilizo o sinalr em asp.net e em mobile apps...se o link exposto acima não lhe ajudar me avise que lhe ajudo...

Comment: @AndreNeto, para você enviar um usuário específico, precisa mapear a conexão do usuário. Favor olhar a resposta. Qualquer coisa me avisar.

Answer (score 0):

Para mandar um usuário específico ou usuários, você precisa mapear usuário para conexão. Existe 4 formas de você fazer isso, entre eles são:

- IUserID provider
- In-memory
- Single-user groups
- Database

Vou dar um exemplo básico de mapear conexão usando **In-memory**:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly static ConnectionMapping<string> _connections = 
            new ConnectionMapping<string>();

        public void Send(string who, string message)
        {
            string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

            foreach (var connectionId in _connections.GetConnections(who))
            {
                Clients.Client(connectionId).addChatMessage(name + ": " + message);
            }
        }

        public override Task OnConnected()
        {
           //é executado quando a conexão se conecta a esta instância do hub.
        }

        public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
        {
          //é executado quando uma conexão se desconecta desta instância do hub.
        }

        public override Task OnReconnected()
        {
          //é executado quando uma conexão de transporte é automaticamente restabelecida depois de ter sido perdida.
        }
    }
```

Doc - Mapeando os usuários de SignalR para conexões: [Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/mapping-users-to-connections)

Doc - Manipuladores de eventos: [Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events)